# Using tabulator / tabspace in a TextView

Tags: android

I wish to use some tabspace in a line where I call setText

```
if(id==R.id.radioButton1){
            title.setText(numbertext.getText()+" Grams");
```

In this case I would like to tab between numbertekst.getText() and the grams.
The output is part of a simple row with values. But as I can't find the tab, the row is a little ugly.

I know I can use multiple textfields or even a table. But as I have a lot of code already I don't want to go that way yet.

I tried the Java way with putting \t, however that seems not to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should add tabulator to the text, but \t don't work in settext. The solution is add the character `\u0009` that represents in unicode char the tabulator, in a string resource.

```
<string name="tab">\u0009</string>

TextView hello = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.helloTextView);

hello.setText("e"+getString(R.string.tab)+"e");
```

just combine more tab to have more space

```
getString(R.string.tab)+getString(R.string.tab)+getString(R.string.tab)
```

Comment: Why do you use a string resource? Simply putting "\u0009" works for me as well.

Answer (score 11):

"\t" works as well, and "\n" is used to start new line

Answer (score 0):

If "\t" doesn't work and \u0009 (Unicode for a tab) only shows 1 space:

In values/strings.xml add

```
<string name="tab">\u0009\u0009\u0009\u0009</string>
```

Then in your Java file add

```
textView.setText("text" + getString(R.string.tab) + "moretext");
```