# How to set cursor retrieved data to text view in Android

Tags: android

i have retrieved some values from DB using the query which is given below.

```
public Cursor getcredittranscation(String date)
{    
    String sql="SELECT A.Acc_No,A.Cust_Name, T.Trans_Amnt FROM TransactionTable "
                + "T LEFT JOIN AccMaster A on A.Acc_ID = T.Acc_ID "
                + "WHERE T.Trans_Date =? AND T.Trans_Type=? ORDER BY  T.Entry_Time asc";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{date, "credit"});

    return cursor;
}
```

And in main activity i want to show these results as a report. Activity code is as given below.

```
try {
    db.open();

    Cursor cur = db.getcredittranscation(temp);
    if(cur.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            DisplayCreditdetails(cur);
        }while(cur.moveToNext());   
    }
    db.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Log.e("Retrive Credit Error ", " "+e.getMessage());
}

private void DisplayCreditdetails(Cursor cur)
{
    String tempstr = " ";
    tempstr ="  "+tempstr +"\t"+ cur.getString(0) + "\t\t\t"
                + cur.getString(1) + "\t\t\t" + cur.getString(2);
    credView.setText(tempstr);

    Log.e("Credit", "Acc No :"+cur.getString(0) +"Name :"+cur.getString(1)+ "Trans Amnt :"+cur.getString(2));
}
```

In log, everything is showing. But in textview only the last value is showing.. what is wrong in my code ??

Comment: you need append instead of setText use `credView.appened(tempstr);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always replace your textview-content by the last string. 
If you want to add all strings and show them in ONE textview, you have to take the old-value of the textview into account.

In this case, you need to do something like:

```
String tempstr = credView.getText().toString() + "  ";
tempstr = "  " + tempstr + "\t" + cur.getString(0) + "\t\t\t"
               + cur.getString(1) + "\t\t\t" + cur.getString(2);
credView.setText(tempstr);
```

Like shayan pourvatan pointed out you could also use append:

```
String tempstr = "  ";
tempstr = "  " + tempstr + "\t" + cur.getString(0) + "\t\t\t"
               + cur.getString(1) + "\t\t\t" + cur.getString(2);
credView.append(tempstr);
```

Comment: need one more help.... I want the sum of values in string 2 only...how to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are replacing the text in textView again again till last.
try this:

```
   String newtempstr = " ";    

       private void DisplayCreditdetails(Cursor cur) {

        String tempstr = " ";
            tempstr ="  "+tempstr +"\t"+ cur.getString(0) + "\t\t\t"
                        + cur.getString(1) + "\t\t\t" + cur.getString(2);

            newtempstr = newtempstr+"."+newtempstr;

            credView.setText(newtempstr);
            Log.e("Credit", "Acc No :"+cur.getString(0) +"Name :"+cur.getString(1)+ "Trans Amnt :"+cur.getString(2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

\t doesn't work for settext. You will have to use \u0009 instead. Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571393/using-tabulator-tabspace-in-a-textview)